# How to get the values from a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

My web page looks like this

```
name(textbox1)
email(textbox2)
age(textbox3)
phoneno(textbox4)

submit(button)                            showfile(hyperlink)
```

How can I get the values of textboxes saved in "showfile" web page after `onclick` in the submit button? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you take some time and work on the question, it makes no sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** - based on the OP's comments, i have updated my answer

To pass a value between to pages, try this

In the first page button click event handler, write something like this

```
Session["Name"] = textBox1.text;
```

then go to the page where you want to display

In the design page add a asp.net `Label` control like this

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

and in the page load event handler or whatever event you want to display the text previously stored in the session write the following code

```
lblName.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["Name"]);
```

---

I don't think you can use `textbox1` as id for more than one `TextBox` in your asp.net page, any way you can simply use `textbox1.Text` property to get the text you wanted

Comment: yes i had tried tat but how can i save those values in the showfile webpage

Comment: what do you mean by "save those values" , do you mean to save the values in a file on your Hard disk ?

Comment: those values should be seen in a different webpage when i click the submit button

Comment: Store the value in Session and access it from Session, you can write something like this to store a value in session `Session["name"] = textbox1.Text;` and to retrieve the value from session write `string name = Convert.ToString(Session["name"]);` and then use the variable name to display the value where ever you want

Comment: Session["name"] = textbox1.Text;i should write this in button click rite in form1 and string name = Convert.ToString(Session["name"]); where should i write this 1

Comment: If it is for textbox you can simply set `textBox1.text = "";` after you save the value in session, or you can also set the viewstate property of the textbox to false. If it is for Session, you just do the same thing set `Session["name"] = "";` or call `Session.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't make multiple controls with same id.So Change them to textbox1,textbox2,...After you can take value from the textboxes on button click event like textbox1.text,textbox2.text..etc

Comment: yes i had tried tat but how can i save those values in the showfile webpage

Answer (score 0):

it depend on your controllers type.
let me correct you . you want to get the value of the textboxes when user click on the button.but if you want to get the value of these textboxes in client side use the jquery in a script tag :

```
<script>

        $("input[type=submit]").click(function(){

               //it return the value of first textbox
               $("input[type=text]")[0].val()

        });

</script>
```

but if these textboxes are server side controllers use can set an id for each and use this code :

```
this.textbox1.Text
```

try to ask better question if you did not get you answer.

Comment: i want to save th values entered in the text boxes to a different webpage when i click on the submit button

Comment: set the target attribute of your form to the page you want to send textboxes value.the that page use this to take the textboxes value : Request["TextboxId"]

Answer (score 0):

You can access it in button Click event like

```
 string name=Textbox1.text;
 string email=Textbox2.text;
 decimal Age=Convert.ToDecimal(Textbox3.text);
 string phoneNo=Textbox4.text;
```

Comment: how will this save the values enterd